# gspread + kivy throw issues, separeted work well

Tags: python, kivy, gspread

I want to make a dropdown menu from google spreadsheets titles. While separately the dropdown menu works and I get the info from google spreadsheets, but when I combine the two, there are error messages.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('frisbee.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sh = client.open('Teams')
worksheet_list = sh.worksheets()
wsl = str(worksheet_list).split()

for word in wsl:
    if "Worksheet" in word:
        wsl.remove(word)
for word in wsl:
    if "id" in word:
        wsl.remove(word)
for word in wsl:
    if "<Worksheet" in word:
        wsl.remove(word)

dropdown = DropDown()
for index in range(len(wsl)):
    btn = Button(text=wsl[index], size_hint_y=None, height=44)
    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
    dropdown.add_widget(btn)

mainbutton = Button(text='Teams', size_hint=(None, None))
mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(mainbutton)
```

**Expected result**: A window pop up with the dropdown menu.

**Actual result**:

```
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. It's possible that gspread added support but not when I used to use it

Comment: Try running the following code: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html#create-an-application and tell me if you have problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc it runs if I run it in a different project, it does not in the same library, where I use the gspread.

Comment: @eyllanesc it looks like it's an issue with sd12, as right now it works fine in a different project, the whole copy. in my other project it says sd12- ImportError: DLL load failed, etc